# Primes with digits only 1

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, decimal-expansion, repunit-numbers

Let $Y(k)$ be the number consisting of $1$, repeated $k$ times. We know that $Y(2) =11$ is prime. It so happens that $Y(19)$ and $Y(23)$ are also prime.

Are there any more?

Regards,

David

Comment: Do you mean prime numbers with digits all $1$ ? Google rep-units. The next is $Y(317)$

Comment: Y(n) is prime for n = 2, 19, 23, 317, 1031, ... (sequence A004023 in OEIS).

Comment: The magic words are "Repunit primes". There are five known repunit primes. http://oeis.org/A004023

Comment: @ArturoMagidin and at least one prp

Comment: These numbers are called <shudder> "repunits."  If you search this site for "prime repunit" you'll get lots of hits.

Comment: May (or may not) be worth noting a repunit $Y(k)$ is prime only if $k$ is.  But the converse is obviously not true.

Comment: @ J. W. Tanner This is not to suggest that we know of any more after 1031 or that there are infinitely many of them I presume.

Comment: Richard K. Guy in the 2nd edition of his "Unsolved Problems in Number Theory'' also cites Y(49081) as "probably'' one.

Comment: per OEIS, Y(n) is probably prime for $n=49081, 86453, 109297, 270343, 5794777, $ and $8177207$

Answer (score 6):

To summarize the comments, the repunit $$Y(k)=\frac{10^k-1}9,$$  the number $11...111$ consisting of $k$ copies of the digit $1,$ is known to be prime for

$k=2, 19, 23, 317,$ and $1031.$

Source:   [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A004023).

Comment: Note that if $k$ is composite, then $Y(k)$ is.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied; much appreciated, now I know what a repunit prime is! I came across these when looking at something else, namely:

Comment: Let P(n,k) be the number Y(k)prime(n)Y(k) and sequence a(n) be least k>0 such that P(n,k) is prime, and 0 if no such k exists. I find the following: 0,1,1,3,0,3,1,0,1,1,2,0,3,2,1,0,14,3,0,3,2,1,4,3,0.... The problem is with the zeroes because it is hard to prove that no such k exists. Therefore, though I am certain of the non zero terms the zeroes are best guesses at the moment. I would like to submit this to oeis when and if more is known. Any ideas for proofs most welcome, though the case for prime(5)=11 looks obvious.

Comment: It so happens that Y(19) is the greatest prime divisor of P(2,18), and Y(23) is the greatest prime divisor of P(2,22), which is how I came across them in the first place.

Comment: Why the down vote ?

Comment: ???What vote? I have not (to my knowledge) voted on anything. Was very happy with responses to my first question (thanks). Have tried to ask a follow up question but no replies as yet.

Comment: Somebody downvoted; I don’t know who, but am wondering why