# Determining composite numbers by using geometric progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series

---

I have a problem which involves finding composite numbers among given set of numbers of the form $11111...1$$(n-digits)$.

> Which of the following numbers is/are composite
>
> (i)   $11111...1$$(91-digits)$
>
> (ii)  $11111...1$$(81-digits)$
>
> (iii) $11111...1$$(75-digits)$
>
> (iv)  $11111...1$$(105-digits)$

Now I know that these numbers can be simplified using Geometric series.

$$11111...1(n-digits) = 10^0+10^1+10^2+....+10^{n-1}$$
$$= \Biggl(\frac{10^n-1}{10-1}\Biggr)$$

But I can't further simplify from here so I help for this.

---

I have seen a similar post in MSE [Primes with digits only 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138191/primes-with-digits-only-1) but it was tagged under number theory which I am not familier with, my question is about a specific problem from sequence and series.It would be good if I am able to solve using various sequences and series.

Comment: This has been answered here. Those numbers are rep-units (denoted with $R_n$) , which can only be prime if $n$ is prime. Only nine primes of this form are known, five of them actually proven to be prime.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit

Comment: Indeed, see also [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A004023) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138191/primes-with-digits-only-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those four numbers are compsit.

For the first one we hae $$91=7\times 13$$

Thus we can factor  $1111111$ and the number will be the product of at least two integers.

The other three numbers are divisible by $3$ because sum of their digits are  divisible by $3$

Comment: So how can we factor the first number from the pattern i.e(how can you show that the number is product of two integers from the described pattern)?

Comment: @prankal you get $1111111(1+10^7+10^{14}+...+10^{84}$

Comment: Thank you very much sir for helping me.