# Repunit prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, repunit-numbers

Consider all numbers that are written with only ones in base $10$, that is, numbers of the form
$$
p_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} 10^{i-1}=\frac{10^n-1}{9}=\underbrace{1.....1}_\text{$n$ $1$s}.
$$
Here, $n$ is the number of $1$s in that number. For example, $p_2=11$ and $p_5=11111$.

For which values of $n$ is $p_n$ a prime number? I feel there should be an infinite number of values, but is this true? For example, after a brief computation, I've concluded that, for $1\leq n\leq 10^4 $, $p_n$ is prime if and only if
$$
n\in\{2,19,23,317,1031\},
$$
which are also prime numbers.

In some way, it seems that such primes stop here, but it might simply be the case that the next prime is way bigger than $p_{1031}$. If there are indeed infinitely many primes in such form, is there an efficient way of testing whether $p_n$ is a prime, given $n$?

Comment: A question that is more easily answered is: when is a repunit *not* a prime number. For example when $n$ is even then it will be divisible by $11$ so these are out. Not much harder to see that if $n$ is not a prime then it cannot be a prime.

Comment: OEIS has an entry for these: https://oeis.org/A004023 . You'll probably find out a lot about the problem if you follow the references there. I conjecture that it's not known whether there are infinitely many primes of this sort.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138191/primes-with-digits-only-1)

Answer (score 3):

$\underbrace{1.....1}_\text{$a \cdot b$ $1$s}$ for some  integers a,b

then,

$\underbrace{1.....1}_\text{$a$ $1$s}\underbrace{1.....1}_\text{$a$ $1$s}...\underbrace{1.....1}_\text{$a$ $1$s} $ / $ \underbrace{1.....1}_\text{$a$ $1$s} = integer$

Comment: I'ts not hard to compute this integer but I think you can do it yourself

Comment: you can rewrite starting number to look like 1..11*10^((b-1)*a)+..+1...1 and then divide it with 1...1

Comment: This proves the assertion that all $n$ such that $p_n$ is prime are themselves prime.